# comparing dataset to specific criteria

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, comparison

I try my very best to make my first question here as specific and reproducible as possible.
I have a huge dataset, with annual means or minimums for different parameters (example: TP and O2) of different station (example: Carb_Ben, Carb_uR, OW_Kessin) in different years (2010-2019). Each station belong to a specific type (example: 11_tl_ba,14_ka,23).

```
data<-structure(list(Station = c("Carb_Ben", "Carb_Ben", "Carb_uR", 
"Carb_uR", "Laak_GK", "Laak_GK", "Laak_GK", "OW_Kessin", "OW_Kessin", 
"OW_Kessin"), Typ = c("11_tl_ba", "11_tl_ba", "11_tl_ba", "11_tl_ba", 
"23", "23", "23", "23", "23", "23"), Jahr = structure(c(4L, 7L, 
4L, 7L, 2L, 5L, 8L, 3L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("2010", "2013", "2014", 
"2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019"), class = "factor"), O2_min = c(1.44, 
1.53, 8, 6.7, 2.7, 1.79, 1.4, 4.3, 4.7675, 4.015), TP_mean = c(0.513333333333333, 
0.1625, 0.148333333333333, 0.124166666666667, 0.155, 0.28, 0.175833333333333, 
0.0954166666666667, 0.0929166666666667, 0.0970833333333333)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), groups = structure(list(Station = c("Carb_Ben", "Carb_uR", 
"Laak_GK", "OW_Kessin"), Typ = c("11_tl_ba", "11_tl_ba", "23", 
"23"), .rows = list(1:2, 3:4, 5:7, 8:10)), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

#so the data look like this: 

# A tibble: 10 x 5
# Groups:   Station, Typ [4]
   Station   Typ      Jahr  O2_min TP_mean
   <chr>     <chr>    <fct>  <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 Carb_Ben  11_tl_ba 2015    1.44  0.513 
 2 Carb_Ben  11_tl_ba 2018    1.53  0.162 
 3 Carb_uR   11_tl_ba 2015    8     0.148 
 4 Carb_uR   11_tl_ba 2018    6.7   0.124 
 5 Laak_GK   23       2013    2.7   0.155 
 6 Laak_GK   23       2016    1.79  0.28  
 7 Laak_GK   23       2019    1.4   0.176 
 8 OW_Kessin 23       2014    4.3   0.0954
 9 OW_Kessin 23       2015    4.77  0.0929
10 OW_Kessin 23       2016    4.01  0.0971
```

Then I have the criteria for each parameter and type for a good Status (_g) or very good Status (_sg).

```
criteria<-structure(list(Typ = structure(c(10L, 5L, 24L), .Label = c("10", 
"11_alp", "11_mg_ba", "11_mg_br", "11_tl_ba", "11_tl_br", "12_mg_ba", 
"12_tl_ba", "12_tl_br", "14_ka", "14_si", "15", "15 g", "16_ka", 
"16_si", "17", "18", "19", "19_ba", "2.1", "2.2", "20", "22", 
"23", "3.1", "3.2", "4", "5", "5.1", "6", "6 K", "7", "9", "9.1", 
"9.1 K", "9.2", "B1", "B2a", "B2b", "B3a", "B3b", "Subtyp 21 N"
), class = "factor"), O2_g = c(7L, 6L, 4L), O2_sg = 9:7, TP_g = c(0.1, 
0.15, 0.1), TP_sg = c(0.05, 0.05, 0.05)), row.names = c(24L, 
28L, 37L), class = "data.frame")

#This looks like this:

        Typ O2_g O2_sg TP_g TP_sg
24 11_tl_ba    8     8 0.10  0.05
28    14_ka    7     9 0.10  0.05
27       23    6     8 0.15  0.05
```

Now I want to compare each parameter for each station and each year if it fits the criteria depending on the type. To find out if the status of each parameter at each station in each year is "good" (gut), "very good" (sehr gut) or "not good" (nicht gut)

My solution for this is currently

```
data_criteria<-data%>%
  mutate(GW_O2_g=case_when(Typ=='11_tl_ba' ~criteria$O2_g[which(criteria$Typ=='11_tl_ba')],
                           Typ=='14_ka' ~criteria$O2_g[which(criteria$Typ=='14_ka')],
                           Typ=='23' ~criteria$O2_g[which(criteria$Typ=='23')]),
         GW_O2_sg=case_when(Typ=='11_tl_ba' ~criteria$O2_sg[which(criteria$Typ=='11_tl_ba')],
                            Typ=='14_ka' ~criteria$O2_sg[which(criteria$Typ=='14_ka')],
                            Typ=='23' ~criteria$O2_sg[which(criteria$Typ=='23')]),
         GW_TP_g=case_when(Typ=='11_tl_ba' ~criteria$TP_g[which(criteria$Typ=='11_tl_ba')],
                           Typ=='14_ka' ~criteria$TP_g[which(criteria$Typ=='14_ka')],
                           Typ=='23' ~criteria$TP_g[which(criteria$Typ=='23')]),
         GW_TP_sg=case_when(Typ=='11_tl_ba' ~criteria$TP_sg[which(criteria$Typ=='11_tl_ba')],
                            Typ=='14_ka' ~criteria$TP_sg[which(criteria$Typ=='14_ka')],
                            Typ=='23' ~criteria$TP_sg[which(criteria$Typ=='23')]))%>%
  mutate(GK_O2=case_when(O2_min<GW_O2_g ~'nicht gut',
                         O2_min>=GW_O2_g & O2_min<GW_O2_sg~'gut',
                         O2_min>GW_O2_sg ~ 'sehr gut'),
         GK_TP=case_when(TP_mean>GW_TP_g ~ 'nicht gut',
                         TP_mean<=GW_TP_g & TP_mean>GW_TP_sg ~ 'gut',
                         TP_mean<=GW_TP_sg ~ 'sehr gut'))

#to get this:
# A tibble: 10 x 11
# Groups:   Station, Typ [4]
   Station   Typ      Jahr  O2_min TP_mean GW_O2_g GW_O2_sg GW_TP_g GW_TP_sg GK_O2     GK_TP    
   <chr>     <chr>    <fct>  <dbl>   <dbl>   <int>    <int>   <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>     <chr>    
 1 Carb_Ben  11_tl_ba 2015    1.44  0.513        8        8    0.1      0.05 nicht gut nicht gut
 2 Carb_Ben  11_tl_ba 2018    1.53  0.162        8        8    0.1      0.05 nicht gut nicht gut
 3 Carb_uR   11_tl_ba 2015    8     0.148        8        8    0.1      0.05 sehr gut  nicht gut
 4 Carb_uR   11_tl_ba 2018    6.7   0.124        8        8    0.1      0.05 nicht gut nicht gut
 5 Laak_GK   23       2013    2.7   0.155        6        8    0.15     0.05 nicht gut nicht gut
 6 Laak_GK   23       2016    1.79  0.28         6        8    0.15     0.05 nicht gut nicht gut
 7 Laak_GK   23       2019    1.4   0.176        6        8    0.15     0.05 nicht gut nicht gut
 8 OW_Kessin 23       2014    4.3   0.0954       6        8    0.15     0.05 nicht gut gut      
 9 OW_Kessin 23       2015    4.77  0.0929       6        8    0.15     0.05 nicht gut gut      
10 OW_Kessin 23       2016    4.01  0.0971       6        8    0.15     0.05 nicht gut gut
```

Since I have some more stations and types and much more parameters, my solution means a lot more typing for me and a lot more opportunities to include mistakes.
I'm pretty sure there is a more elegant way to do this with the same result, but so far I'm not that deep in R to figure out how to do?

Therefore I would be very happy if anybody has a nice simple solution ;).

Answer (score 0):

You may repeatedly select from `criteria` using `match`. `within` helps to keep the code concise.

```
dat <- within(dat, {
  GW_O2_g <- criteria[match(dat$Typ, criteria$Typ), "O2_g"]
  GW_O2_sg <- criteria[match(dat$Typ, criteria$Typ), "O2_sg"]
  GW_TP_g <- criteria[match(dat$Typ, criteria$Typ), "TP_g"]
  GW_TP_sg <- criteria[match(dat$Typ, criteria$Typ), "TP_sg"]
  GK_O2 <- NA
  GK_O2[O2_min < GW_O2_g] <- "nicht gut"
  GK_O2[O2_min >= GW_O2_g & O2_min < GW_O2_sg] <- "gut"
  GK_O2[O2_min > GW_O2_sg] <- "sehr gut"
  GK_TP <- NA
  GK_TP[TP_mean > GW_TP_g] <- "nicht gut"
  GK_TP[TP_mean <= GW_TP_g & TP_mean > GW_TP_sg] <- "gut"
  GK_TP[TP_mean <= GW_TP_sg] <- "sehr gut"
})
# # A tibble: 10 x 11
# # Groups:   Station, Typ [4]
#    Station   Typ      Jahr  O2_min TP_mean GK_TP     GK_O2     GW_TP_sg GW_TP_g GW_O2_sg GW_O2_g
#    <chr>     <chr>    <fct>  <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>     <chr>        <dbl>   <dbl>    <int>   <int>
#  1 Carb_Ben  11_tl_ba 2015    1.44  0.513  nicht gut nicht gut     0.05    0.15        8       6
#  2 Carb_Ben  11_tl_ba 2018    1.53  0.162  nicht gut nicht gut     0.05    0.15        8       6
#  3 Carb_uR   11_tl_ba 2015    8     0.148  gut       NA            0.05    0.15        8       6
#  4 Carb_uR   11_tl_ba 2018    6.7   0.124  gut       gut           0.05    0.15        8       6
#  5 Laak_GK   23       2013    2.7   0.155  nicht gut nicht gut     0.05    0.1         7       4
#  6 Laak_GK   23       2016    1.79  0.28   nicht gut nicht gut     0.05    0.1         7       4
#  7 Laak_GK   23       2019    1.4   0.176  nicht gut nicht gut     0.05    0.1         7       4
#  8 OW_Kessin 23       2014    4.3   0.0954 gut       gut           0.05    0.1         7       4
#  9 OW_Kessin 23       2015    4.77  0.0929 gut       gut           0.05    0.1         7       4
# 10 OW_Kessin 23       2016    4.01  0.0971 gut       gut           0.05    0.1         7       4
```

Comment: Thank you! Still a lot of typing but quite more straightforward than before.